# Manipulate Nextflow variables outside of scripts

Tags: python, groovy, workflow, nextflow

I have a process iterate_list. Process iterate_list takes a list and does something on each item in the list. When running the script, it takes two inputs. The list and the item it needs to process (which it gets as a consumer from a rabbitmq queue)

Currently, I give a python script the entire list, and it iterates over each one does the processing (as one big chunk) and returns after completion. This is fine, however, if the system restarts, it starts all over again.

I was wondering, how can I make it so that every time my python script processes a single item, it returns the item, I remove it from the list, and then pass in the new list to the process. So in case of a system restart/crash, nextflow knows where it left off and can continue from there.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def cfg_file = new File('/config.json')
def analysis_config = jsonSlurper.parse(cfg_file)
def cfg_json = cfg_file.getText()
def list_of_items_to_process = [] 

items = Channel.from(analysis_config.items.keySet())

for (String item : items) {
    list_of_items_to_process << item
    } 

process iterate_list{
    echo true

    input:
    list_of_items_to_process

    output:
    val 1 into typing_cur

    script:
    """
    python3.7 process_list_items.py ${my_queue} \'${list_of_items_to_process}\'
    """ 
}

process signal_completion{

    echo true

    input:
    val typing_cur

    script:
    """
    echo "all done!"
    """
}
```

Basically, the process "iterate_list" takes one "item" from a queue in the message broker. Process iterate_list should look something like:

```
process iterate_list{
    echo true

    input:
    list_of_items_to_process

    output:
    val 1 into typing_cur

    script:
    """
    python3.7 process_list_items.py ${my_queue} \'${list_of_items_to_process}\'
    list_of_items_to_process.remove(<output from python script>)
    """
}
```

And so for each one, it shd run, remove the item it jus processed, and restart with a new list.

```
initial_list = [1,2,3,4]
after_first_process_completes = [2,3,4]
and_eventually = [] <- This is when it should move on to the next process.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like what you're really trying to do is manipulate a global `ArrayList` from within a Nextflow process. AFAIK, there's no way to do that exactly. This is what [channels](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html) are for.

It's not clear if you actually need to remove any items from your list of items to process. Nextflow can already use cached results using the `-resume` option. So why not just pass in the full list and a single item for processing?

```
items = Channel.from(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])

items.into {
    items_ch1
    items_ch2
}

process iterate_list{

    input:
    val item from items_ch1
    val list_of_items_to_process from items_ch2.collect()

    """
    python3.7 process_list_items.py "${item}" '${list_of_items_to_process}'
    """
}
```

I can only guess as to how your Python script uses its arguments, but if your list of items to process is just a placeholder then you may even be able to input a single element list of items to process:

```
items = Channel.from(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])

process iterate_list{

    input:
    val item from items

    """
    python3.7 process_list_items.py "${item}" '[${item}]'
    """
}
```

Comment: Since nextflow doesn't permit the use of Google Cloud Filestore, I was sort of abusing the workflow by having it handle my rabbitmq RPC and not really do the work itself. But that's changing, and now my biggest problem is storage. 

How can I use input from a cloud storage bucket. And then how can I process the file and upload it back to the output bucket. I'll ask this question tomorrow. Nextflow has a small community.

Comment: @daudnadeem: Basically just specify them using the `gs://` protocol, eg `gs://yourbucket/path_to_file`. Then be sure to specify a GS bucket where your workflow's intermediate results are to be stored. You can do this using the `-work-dir` option, eg `nextflow run main.nf -work-dir gs://yourbucket/project/workdir`. You may also like to use a custom parameter perhaps called `--outdir` to specify a GS bucket to publish your outputs using the [publishDir](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#publishdir) directive. Then add `--outdir gs://yourbucket/project/results` to your cmd line.

Comment: Alright. Suppose I have a file gs://this-bucket/file.txt and I give work-dir as gs://this-bucket, if I want to access the file do I point to it as gs://this-bucket/file.txt or would Nextflow download this file to the local storage and I simply call it as file.txt?

Comment: @daudnadeem: Actually I think you'll need to specify a bucket sub-directory as your work-dir, as per the tip [here](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/google.html#pipeline-execution). But you should be able to just point to your file as `gs://this-bucket/file.txt`. Then, for example, in your script include the lines `params.foobar = "gs://this-bucket/file.txt"` and `foobar = file(params.foobar)`, then you should be able to include it in any of your processes, i.e. `process baz { input: file(foobar) ... }`

Comment: @daudnadeem: "Any input data not stored in a Google Storage bucket will automatically be transferred to the pipeline work bucket" - from [here](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/google.html#id5)